# asp.net core 3.1 web api https hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have deployed web api project which i developed with aspnet core 3.1 to the prod server running IIS. I simply made the configurations needed(hosting bundle, no managed code app. pool), created the website and succesfully hosted over http. However when i add https binding to website(including trusted self signed certificate), web api doesnt work on neither http nor https and doesnt response any error.(I am calling the api localy using postman)

I want to learn if i need to make any configuration at application level? Because in this scenario, kestrel is deployed with IIS reverse proxy and as far as i searched, iis configuration might be enough for https binding. By the way, iis version is 8.5.9600

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Verify bindings using a tool like Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html 2. Use a web browser to test out your Web API. Postman might fail due to its configuration, so you need another way as reference.

Comment: Thank you ver much. After installing the app you mentioned, i realized that i need to open the port from the firewall settings. Now it is working.